# Declare and define a variable globally (within Module)?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a module ("Module1") which has a few macros.  Some of those I run back to back (it splits up the code length and makes it easier to debug/troubleshoot).  At the top of that module, I have:

```
Option explicit
Dim addressFileName as String

Sub noOne()
addressFileName = "C:\Batman.xslx"
End Sub

Sub noTwo()
msgbox("You want to use the file " & addressFileName)
End Sub
```

Works great if I run noOne() then noTwo() after it.  However, if I have to debug in subTwo() and start the macro over, it doesn't recognize "addressFileName".

Is there a way I can define `addressFileName` to be used globally as well?  Simply adding `addressFileName = "C:\Batman.xslx` after declaring it doesn't work ("Compile error: Invalid outside procedure").

Is this possible? Or is there perhaps some workaround?  Or is there a good reason you can't do this (if so, I'd love to know!).  Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can define addressFileName to be used globally as well?

Use

```
public const addressFileName as string  = "C:\Batman.xslx"
```

Note that you will not be able to alter the string but it can be referenced from anywhere in your project. This needs to be at the top of a module sheet, not a worksheet code sheet. See [Declaring Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264636.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped! That's it.  

Are there any big downsides from using global constants instead of declaring them in each Macro?

Quick question: If I define that globally, then in sub noTwo() change it to  `addressFileName = "C:\Superman"`, will it revert back to the global definition (C:\Batman) or will it remain the most recent declaration ("C:\Superman")?

Comment: **Note that you will not be able to alter the string**. It won't revert because you cannot change it to start. I use globals for many frequently used strings; base URLs come to mind. The downside is that **you will not be able to alter the string**. `Const` is short for constant and the var wouldn't be constant if you could change it. The bonus is that you only need to manually adjust them in one place if circumstances change.

Comment: D'oh! Yes yes, now I remember `const` from C language.  Thanks a ton Jeeped!

Comment: Glad you got sorted out quickly. As far as your previous situation goes, you could call noOne from within noTwo (before the msgbox) and that would satisfy the debugger.